# Checking for form correctness in visual basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I'm developing a small web app using ASP.net/VB.net4 that contains an important form on one of the pages.  I need to make sure that the form is filled out correctly, and have decided to go with custom logic to do this, writing each check by hand and checking every element on the page.

My **question** is actually more fundamental here -- I have the checks written to make sure that the form passes correctness, but I don't actually know in what programmatical structure to put these checks.

For now, I put the checks in an infinite loop in my Visual Basic code behind.

```
While (True)
        If (...) Then
            MsgBox("One or more of your phone numbers is improperly formatted.  You will be given 20 seconds to correct this mistake.  If the mistake is not corrected in 20 seconds, you will be eliminated. Good luck.")
        ElseIf (...) Then
             ...............
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
```

Upon hitting the submit button, the loop activates and the checks are completed -- however, there is an issue with this method.  When the form is not correct, then my alert message continues to pop up infinitely and does not allow the user to exit out.  If anyone knows how to avoid this, that would be an appreciated place to start.  Furthermore, the default alert box for VB.net is just ugly and unprofessional, I would prefer something in-browser if possible, rather than just an ugly Windows alert message box.

I've seen a lot of sites now going with a dynamic check; that is, as you fill out the form, if at any point your entry is not formatted properly or is incorrect, you get an automatic alert that tells you this and perhaps the text box color changes to red.  I would like to do it this way, if possible, since this seems easier for the user.  However, I do not know how to do this and have had trouble finding information online about how to implement this.  I believe this is an example of AJAX/jQuery usage but it has been a while since I've used them.

This is a painfully common thing to have to do, forms logic that is.  I know there are a million and a half ways to do this, but does anyone have any advice or recommendation on how to implement this?  Should I be trying to use vb.net (code behind), javascript, or some other way?

Comment: Why custom logic? Why not validator controls (which can be custom as well if needed)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/debza5t0(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You might want to start with [asp.net webforms field validation](https://www.google.com/#q=asp.net+webforms+field+validation). The built-in controls do both client- and srver-side validation. The former for responsiveness, the latter for if the client "adjusted" the values on their way to the server.

Comment: Great, i will check out both of these things.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.  Other answers are welcome.  Seems I have a good chunk of reading and research to do.